# Spring security : make every page redirect if the user doesn't meet a specific criteria

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, spring-security, filter

I am developing a web app that uses Spring Security as the authentication / authorization provider.  Here is how i configure it :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()

        //Allow resources for all pages
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()

        //Allow or disallow specific routes depending on user privileges

        //Users
        .antMatchers("/users/", "users/search").hasAuthority("View Users")
        .antMatchers("/users/add", "/users/edit/*", "/users/delete/*").hasAuthority("Edit Users")

        .antMatchers("/roles/", "roles/search").hasAuthority("View Roles")
        .antMatchers("/roles/add", "/roles/edit/*", "/roles/delete/*").hasAuthority("Edit Roles")

        .antMatchers("/permissions/", "permissions/search").hasAuthority("View Permissions")

        //A million other antMatchers here...

        //All custom routes require authentication
        .anyRequest().authenticated()

        //Custom login page and handling
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .successHandler(loginHandler())
            .failureUrl("/login_error")             
            .permitAll()

        //Custom logout handling with POST request and logout handler for auditing
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler())
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout_success")
            .permitAll()

        //Invalidate the session and delete the JSESSIONID cookie on logout
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

I do not want to post too much code (I will if needed) but essentially my users are stored in a database and i use an extension of UserDetails and UserDetailsService to interact between Spring Security and the DB.  In my User entity, i have a boolean field that controls whether the user needs to change his password (first login).  To achieve this functionality upon the user logging in, i have the following AuthenticationSuccessHandler :

```
    public class LoginHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PreferenceService preferenceService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        User user = userService.findById(((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getId());

        if (user.isMustChangePassword())
        {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/users/initialPasswordChange");
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + getAnchorPageURL(user));
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when logging in, the behavior is exactly as I want it.  The initial password change page does not have a menu but nothing prevents the user from modifying the URL and landing on the home page without changing their password.  In the old Spring MVC days i would have built a custom Filter class running on every page that would have checked if the user logged in had that field set to true and redirected to the initial password change page.  That way, the whole site would have been inaccessible until the password was changed no matter what the user did.

Is there a more elegant, Spring Security-ey way to do this nowadays?

Again I will provide more code if that can help, didn't want to flood my post and wanted to include the most relevant bits first.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the old Spring MVC Filter approach.  Is there a better, pure Spring Security way of doing this?

```
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"}, description = "initialPasswordChangeFilter")
public class InitialPasswordChangeFilter implements Filter
{
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException 
    {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        Filter.super.init(fc);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        try
        {
            SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) req.getSession(false).getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

            User user = userService.findById(((UserDetails) sci.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId());

            String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();

            if (user.isMustChangePassword() && !url.contains("initial") && !url.contains("/webjars") && !url.contains("/css") && 
                !url.contains("/js") && !url.contains("/images"))
            {
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/users/initialPasswordChange");
            }
            else
            {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex)
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```